# I start the GAN network and get a message - Function call stack: keras_scratch_graph

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network

Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-02-01 13:25:02.491404: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
Model: "sequential_1"

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               401920    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257       
=================================================================
Total params: 533,505
Trainable params: 533,505
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 256)               25856     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 256)               1024      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 512)               131584    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              525312    
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_5 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 1024)              4096      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 784)               803600    
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 28, 28, 1)         0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,493,520
Trainable params: 1,489,936
Non-trainable params: 3,584
```

---

> D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:297:
>   UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected
>   trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling
>   `model.compile` after ?   'Discrepancy between trainable weights and
>   collected trainable' 0 [D loss: 0.860389, acc.: 18.75%] [G loss:
>   0.704660] D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py:297:
>   UserWarning: Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected
>   trainable weights, did you set `model.trainable` without calling
>   `model.compile` after ?   'Discrepancy between trainable weights and
>   collected trainable' 2020-02-01 13:25:10.037836: W
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217]
>   BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Failed precondition: Error while
>   reading resource variable _AnonymousVar32 from Container: localhost.
>   This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found:
>   Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar32/class tensorflow::Var does not
>   exist.     [[{{node mul/ReadVariableOp}}]] Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "D:/MachineLearning/Machine Learning A-Z Template
>   Folder/Part 8 - Deep Learning/Section 40 - Convolutional Neural
>   Networks (CNN)/GAN_Keras_Super_Resolution_1.py", line 165, in 
>       gan.train(epochs=300, batch_size=32, sample_interval=20)   File "D:/MachineLearning/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 8 - Deep
>   Learning/Section 40 - Convolutional Neural Networks
>   (CNN)/GAN_Keras_Super_Resolution_1.py", line 124, in train
>       d_loss_real = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(imgs, valid)   File
>   "D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1514, in train_on_batch
>       outputs = self.train_function(ins)   File "D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py",
>   line 3726, in **call**
>       outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)   File "D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py",
>   line 1529, in **call**
>       return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)   File "D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py",
>   line 1569, in _call_impl
>       return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)   File
>   "D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py",
>   line 1670, in _call_flat
>       ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))   File "D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py",
>   line 523, in call
>       ctx=ctx)   File "D:\MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py",
>   line 67, in quick_execute
>       six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)   File "", line 3, in raise_from
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: 
>   Error while reading resource variable _AnonymousVar32 from Container:
>   localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not
>   found: Resource localhost/_AnonymousVar32/class tensorflow::Var does
>   not exist.     [[node mul/ReadVariableOp (defined at
>   \MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009)
>   ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_1753]
>
> Function call stack: keras_scratch_graph

I tried to use the tips I found in community answers to similar questions, but they do not work. Could you help me!

Comment: Hello Sergiy Isakov and welcome to StackOverflow! We need a **[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** to help you out!

Comment: Hello
Can anybody help me?